# Is my packet format is correct for converting h.264 data to .mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I am going to convert h.264 stream data to .mp4 using ffmpeg

SPS NALU:67 64 00 1F AC 56 50 20 06 1A 6E 04 04 04 0D A0 88 46 58

PPS NALU:28 EE 37 27

I made raw file using these above NALUs as follows:

|0x 00 00 00 01  |  SPS  |  0x 00 00 01  |  PPS  |  frame data   |  0x 00 00 01|

my raw file is here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc9s9mll6ev9aoq/sps_pps_payload?dl=0

and frame data it self: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibs7io0aprpo66e/packet1?dl=0

using following command at ffmpeg:

ffmpeg.exe -f h264 -i RawInputFile -vcodec copy -r 25 OutPutFilename.mp4

But it always gives:
missing picture in access unit with size XXXXX

no frame!

decoding for stream 0 failed

Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 : unspecified size

Where am i wrong?

Comment: I am also waiting to hear the inputs from experts..!!

Answer (score 1):

How are you generating the "RawInputFile"? Looking at the SPS, PPS buffer there are different frame headers, 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 in case of SPS 0x00 0x00 0x01 in case of PPS. Though it should not be the problem.

But there are different NAL headers as well, in case of SPS it is **0x67** and in case of PPS it **0x28**. The lower five bits of the NAL represents the frame type

e.g.

0x67 & 0x1f = 0x07 which is SPS

0x28 & 0x1f = 0x08 which is PPS

But why the upper three bits are changing? Need to check what these 3 bits represent.

Regarding your question, FFMPEG or any other muxer expects input stream in following format,

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x67 <<......SPS frame......>>

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x68 <<......PPS frame.......>>

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x65 <<......I frame........>>

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x61 <<......P frame........>>

.

.

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x67 <<......SPS frame......>>

0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x68 <<......PPS frame......>>

**Note :** 
Here 0x67, 0x68 etc are for example purpose only, upper 3 bits can change.

Comment: hi @pragnesh, for which upper 4 bytes changing you are asking?

Comment: Its was a typo i meant bits not bytes. Sorry about that.

Comment: i still confused here, Should i use each time 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 (four bytes) for every 1 byte data?

Comment: can u tell me how i identify I frame and p frame? and for which four bits are changing to you. (+ 1 to you for your responses)

Comment: Do the AND operation with the byte followed by the header (i.e. 0x00 0x00, 0x00, 0x01). if that is equal to 5 that means its an I frame. In your sps_pps_payload file you can find following pattern 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x67 <SPS data> 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x28 <PPS data>. So in case of SPS the upper 3 bits = 3 in case of PPS it is 1

Comment: i not found i frame in my  sps_pps_payload file. Actually i am getting frame data from other sources and i have made this file by placing sps pps and frame data together. frame data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibs7io0aprpo66e/packet1?dl=0

Comment: for details of packet information, you can see this document http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html#screenmirroring-streampackets  for streampackets

Comment: I checked all the packets not found any where I Frame, is it possible to make .mp4 file without I frame data?

Comment: No, I frame is must. I am wondering why you are receiving these kind of frames? Nobody can play the file without I frame, so it should be somewhere in your stream.

Comment: its look like, frame data is encrypted with AES encryption

Answer (score 0):

you will get "missing picture in access unit with size xxxx" if you do not complete your file with a keyframe (I frame).
Just make sure that last frame of your file is I frame.